# Recursive JS Function To Move Specific Characters To End Of String

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, substring, coding-style

For Example:

1. moveAllXToEnd("xxre") --> "rexx"
2. moveAllXToEnd("xxhixx") --> "hixxxx"
3. moveAllXToEnd("xhixhix") --> "hihixxx"

```
function moveAllXToEnd(str, count = 1) {

    if (str.length <= 1) {
        return str;
    }

    // console.log(str.length, count);
    if (str.length === count) {
        return str;
    }

    if (str[count] === 'x') {
        // Removing the x and putting the '' empty string
        let splicedString = str.substr(0, count) + '' + str.substr(count + 1);
        // Adding back the 'x' to the end of the string
        splicedString += str[count];
        return moveAllXToEnd(splicedString, count + 1);
    }

    return moveAllXToEnd(str, count + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test whether the *first* character of the string argument is `x`. If so, return the recursive call *concatenated with `x`* - otherwise, return the first character concatenated with the recursive call:

```js
console.log(moveAllXToEnd("xxre")) // --> "rexx"
console.log(moveAllXToEnd("xxhixx")) // --> "hixxxx"
console.log(moveAllXToEnd("xhixhix")) // --> "hihixxx"
function moveAllXToEnd(str) {
  if (str.length <= 1) {
    return str;
  }
  return str[0] === 'x'
    ? moveAllXToEnd(str.slice(1)) + 'x'
    : str[0] + moveAllXToEnd(str.slice(1));
}
```

The `count` variable doesn't look to serve a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a concatenation of all non target characters with all target characters appended to the end:

```js
function moveAllXToEnd (input) {
    return input.replace(/x+/g, "") + input.replace(/[^x]+/g, "");
}

console.log(moveAllXToEnd("xxre"));
console.log(moveAllXToEnd("xxhixx"));
console.log(moveAllXToEnd("xhixhix"));
```

The first term making up `output` is just the original input with all x's stripped off.  To that, we concatenate at the end all the x's in in the input.